# aarch64-linux-android-gcc error on Ubuntu 16.04 "poll.h" not found

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, gcc, gnu-toolchain

Hi I am trying to cross compile code for Android arm64 on Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc-4.9 from android-ndk and cannot get rid of this error:

```
aarch64-linux-android-gcc -o test.o -c test.c -Os -fPIE -Wall -DDBG
test.c:26:18: fatal error: poll.h: No such file or directory
#include <poll.h>
              ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'test.o' failed
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

I think it is because the toolchain cannot be accessed the right way because before I got:

```
make: aarch64-linux-android-as: Command not found
```

Please advise.

Comment: Are you compiling your own code or someone else's? What is `poll.h`? Is this from some API or is it your own header file?

Comment: It's in the header `#include <poll.h>` should be served by the toolchain

Comment: Just checking, have you converted default NDK toolchain to [standalone](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you yugr, turning it into standalone solved it:

```
$NDK/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py \
--arch arm64 --api 23 --install-dir /tmp/my-android-toolchain
```

After that I added `/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin` to PATH and it worked.